# How do I fix my tab delimited file when there are too many tabs?

Tags: data-cleaning

I have this text file that is supposed to be tab delimited, except that in a couple of fields, there are tabs instead of spaces, making it hard to extract the data I need. It's too large to manually fix it, so I need any solution.

The columns SHOULD look something like this:

```
A\tB\tC\tsome info\tGO:123\t
```

But occassionally i get this:

```
A\tB\tC\tsome\tinfo\tGO:123\t
```

And the "some info" column can be any number of things, so i can't just sed replace. What should be column 5 always starts with "GO:" and columns 1, 2, and 3 are always correct. It's just this 4th column that's making things hard.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression:

```
(A)\\t(B)\\t(C)\\t(.*)?\\t(GO:123)\\t
```

Get groups 1,2,3,4. You have your `some data` with and without tab in group 4.